# Typescript type inference for function parameter's return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

in my react project I declare my api requests with this pattern:

```
export type LoginApiResponse = {
  token: string,
  user: User
}

export function login(email: string, password: string): Promise<LoginApiResponse> {
  return AuthService.signinWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}
```

and I consume them through a custom hook

```
export function useApi<T, Fn extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>>(
  fn: Fn
) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const execute = async (...params: Parameters<Fn>) => {

    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const result = await fn(...params);
      setLoading(false);
      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn("sideEfect execution error", err, JSON.stringify(err));
      setError(err);
      setLoading(false);
      throw (error);
    }
  };
  return { loading, execute, error };
}
```

with an implementation like this

const loginExecutor = useApi<LoginApiResponse, typeof api.login>(api.login)

In this way I encapsulate loading and error state for a given api request, plus I have full typing support

[image]

[image]

**THE QUESTION**

Now my question is: is there a way to take advantage of typescript type inference to infer the return type and parameters type of the fn function in order to be able to write

```
useApi(api.login)
```

instead of

```
useApi<LoginApiResponse, typeof api.login>(api.login)
```

While keeping the same strong typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your example infers everything except a response. It has the following type:

```
const loginExecutor = useApi(login)

const loginExecutor: {
    loading: boolean;
    execute: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<unknown>;
    error: string;
}
```

Try on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAyEDmBLAdgQTGwCVgBnSXM1AXjgG8BYAKDgQgGthcAuOMmFDyYANCzYBXalD4ChuTCwC%20LFqEiw4AMwm4AxjGwRccADZY8ACmABbAIbZTswcJFwwdsmQDu0ACbO8pgAlHwAClAQNtjUADwYOAREpBTG1AB8DOJwUMAwElAmEVExwAB0uWQQpgBuwJZMzACQbDCc3HwA5J1izZLSXZ3ZSsHKqszq0PA6%20obGcFLAhNixACpuAGImoDDcfmRwlmXHdlCYZHx2uIgA2gC6wXA0mcXRcavp6ZbZWrxwWyxHo02Ho0vAbuY7H5XPw8hgocI7k84DctHZTNQ3JYanwAEYQarAK6PZ4LXB%20YBaPDAPx3ADc2VBVHBwCgkSgbmoMAAomzoEi6DdulicfwXAoSZldBSqbgafTGWC4KBgHoJLtkZ5EPpDscyh4oHYbBc4GFTka8qyyLEtulJVlmNk2Fz4dCFJZBBJgMEGY7WGwEFBEA6AwGmQIcuQJKZ4HQ7N4HNNcEdjgajWQfU6Ay6IAj3WiMd7faG2Ll8oVI2RozBiwGlHA9HYYHoABaHVlQIFZkFpQllBOFSwAIjI2Ap3K0qvgKrVc22fKgQ7cHbcACkAMoAeQAcmU5MJsFpENY2cFM-7Q1zeeyT53a5e4bm3ZhLAXqOeSwgW5FvO2Fx%2062GWsywKEx6DMJ8YRndVgGXBc4CUX0VD9cN4HMRJuRAVV1WgZFFmWSx0LwUY-SI3BMOwtooDKaDdnGIA)

---

I updated `useApi` to extract args and return type separarly:

```
export function useApi<A extends any[], T>(
  fn: (...args: A) => Promise<T>
)
```

So now we get following type:

```
const loginExecutor = useApi(login)
const loginExecutor: {
    loading: boolean;
    execute: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<LoginApiResponse>;
    error: string;
}
```

Try on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAyEDmBLAdgQTGwCVgBnSXM1AXjgG8BYAKDgQgGthcAuOMmFDyYANCzYBXalD4ChuTCwC%20LFqEiw4AMwm4AxjGwRccADZY8ACmABbAIbZTswcJFwwdsmQDu0ACbO8pgAlHwAClAQNtjUADwYOAREpBTG1AB8DOJwUMAwElAmEVExwAB0uWQQpgBuwJZMzACQbDCc3HwA5J1izZLSXZ3ZSsHKqszq0PA6%20obGcFLAhNix%20HCgMNx%20ZHB2uIgA2gC6bgAq6ZbZWrxwlmX3dlCYZHz4wXA0mcXRcecs7402Ho0vADuY7H5XPw8hgIcIjh84ActHZTNQ3JYanwAEYQarAPbvT4LXB%20YBaPDAPxHADc2WBVFBwCgkSgbmoMAAoizoAi6AduhisfwXAoiZldGSKbgqbT6SD1iBgHoJJtEZ5EPpbvcyh4oHYbC84GFHga8syyLE7g8nka3h8vpEfsBYud0uKssxsmwObDIQpLIIJMBgnSvaw2AgoIhPZHIwyBDlyBJTPA6HZvA5prhrbrTYbQ97I76IHCAyi0SGw3G2Ll8oUk2QUzBq5GlHA9HYYHoABa3ZlQAFFoFpfFlTOFSwAIjI2DJnK0yvgoGVqqMJgH0CnbgHbgAUgBlADyADkynJhNgtIhrCzgoWI3GOdzWbfB62nzDS-7MJYK9QHxrBAe0ibx%20x5d8ixUCMlFbOsChMegzG-KEVxVTYdwguBYLGcME3gcxEk5JV0OgRFFmWSxCLwUZw2o3BiNXNooDKNDVWAcYgA)

---

Please note that my examples were tested on TS >= 4.